# How to fix "TypeError: this.props.messages.map is not a function" in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to pass props down to my component via mapDispatchToProps(). However, I encountered this problem

```
TypeError: this.props.messages.map is not a function
DisplayMessages.render
C:/Users/User/Desktop/Project/first-react-redux/src/DisplayMessages.js:38
  35 |             <h2>Type in a new message</h2>
  36 |             <input value={input} onChange={this.handleChange} />
  37 |             <button onClick={this.submitMessage}>Submit</button>
> 38 |             <ul>{this.props.messages.map((message, index) => <li key={index}>{message}</li>)}</ul>
     | ^  39 |         </div >
  40 |     )
  41 | }
```

My page can be displayed if I uncomment line 38. However, upon clicking the button I receive this error message:

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
submitNewMessage
C:/Users/User/Desktop/Project/first-react-redux/src/DisplayMessagesContainer.js:18
  16 |     return {
  17 |         submitNewMessage: (newMessage) => {
> 18 |             dispatch(addMessage(newMessage))
  19 |         }
  20 |     }
  21 | };
```

I am new to React-redux and I am not sure what went wrong. The example I am currently working on is from freecodecamp, and I have tested these codes in the code editor and passed the challenge (except this time I am doing it on my own machine and structuring my own file tree.)

This is how my component looks like:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class DisplayMessages extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            input: '',
        }
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            input: event.target.value
        })
    }

    submitMessage = () => {
        this.props.submitNewMessage(this.state.input)
        this.setState({
            input: '',
       })
    }


    render() {
        const { input} = this.state
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Type in a new message</h2>
                <input value={input} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                <button onClick={this.submitMessage}>Submit</button>
                <ul>{this.props.messages.map((message, index) => <li key={index}>{message}</li>)}</ul>
            </div >
        )
    }
}
```

And this is my container:

```
import DisplayMessages from './DisplayMessages';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import addMessage from './redux/actions'

mapStateToProps
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { messages: state }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        submitNewMessage: (message) => {
            dispatch(addMessage(message))
        }
    }
};

const DisplayMessagesContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DisplayMessages)

export default DisplayMessagesContainer
```

My reducer.js:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import types from './types';

const defaultState = [];
const messageReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.ADD:
            return [...state].concat(action.message)
            break;
        default:
            return state
    }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    message: messageReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

My action.js for action creators:

```
import types from './types.js';

const addMessage = (message) => {
    return {
        type: types.ADD,
        message: message
    }
}

export default {
    addMessage,
}
```

And my type.js:

```
const ADD = "ADD"

export default {
    ADD,
}
```

So what actually went wrong with my code?

Any help regarding this is much appreaciated.

Thanks

---

EDIT:
I have confirmed that this.props.messages is an Object not an array. But my further question is: why was I able to map over an Object in the code editor in freecodecamp but not now? And how do I fix this issue?

Comment: Where did you define your messages array? If it's not an array then you can't map over it.

Comment: Hey, I've edited my question to include some other files that are relevant. I define my messages array in my reducers.js. Is there an alternative way to map over an object? Because I have confirmed that "this.props.messages" is an object. Also, do you know why I was able to map over an object in the code editor in freecodecamp but not now?

Comment: Im really not sure why, but as i am aware of you can't map over object, because map is array function.

Comment: Not related, but when you use es6, you can use `[...state, action.message]`  instead of `[...state].concat(action.message)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your reducer you have defined

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    message: messageReducer
});
```

should you set mapStateToProps like this ?

```
//mapStateToProps
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { messages: state.message }
};
```

Because you don't want to set whole state as messages props (and state is object), you want to set messages as state.message (message => name from reducer).

*Edit* 
To be honest i've never user mapDispatchToProps like that, i just import actions and pass them like second parameter to connect(...)
`actions` is your default export and it contains function `addMessage`, that function, and all other will be put to props when you pass them like this.
and if you make named export

```
//named export example 
export const addMessage()...
//import would be like
import {addMessage} from './redux/actions'
//passing to connect would be like 
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {addMessage});
```

and usage would be same as example under.

for example

```
import actions from './redux/actions'

// inside DisplayMessages  i use action like
 submitMessage = () => {
        this.props.addMessage(this.state.input)
        this.setState({
            input: '',
       })
    }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(DisplayMessages)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks ! this solves the mapping issue ! But I still get an error when i click the button. Error message like so: "TypeError: Object(...) is not a function". When i console.log "typeof(this.props.submitNewMessage)" the result i get is a function, not an object. So I'm confused as to why the error message says its an object and not a function.

Comment: Glad i could help. I've made small edit update on this answer. It's how i use actions and dispatch them when working with redux.

Answer (score 0):

@chubbybunny `map function` only works with arrays. check if `this.props.messages` is an array.

Comment: Hi, I have checked that this.props.messages is an object. Can I know why was I able to map over an object in the freecodecamp editor but not now when I'm doing it on my own machine? I went over to freecodecamp and redo the example and console.log -ed "this.props.messages" and it was an object there as well.

Answer (score 0):

1) You should add default props like
DisplayMessages.defaultProps = {
  messages:[]
}

2) Check the messages type in mapstatetoprops whether it is array or object.
3) map works only on array